# Django - How do we send dict and model objects as json

Tags: python, json, django

I have model classes `BookDetails` and `ReaderReviews`.

Here is my class in `views.py` that tries to return `BookDetail` info and also checks if the logged-in user already posted a review about this book.

`user_review` is a dict which checks if the user already posted a review. I would like to return `user_review` dict and `book_info` as json. I am not sure how to return the dict and model data.

views.py:

```
class Book(DetailView):
    model = BookDetails
    context_object_name = "bookobject"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(Book,self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['book_reviews'] = ReaderReviews.objects.filter(review_id__exact=str(self.kwargs['pk']))
        return context


    def render_to_response(self, context, **response_kwargs):

        #import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

        #default value for review_flag
        user_review = {"review_flag":'0'}

        #Check if the user already posted review about the book
        for book_review in context['book_reviews']:

            if book_review.user.username == self.request.user.username:
                user_review["review_flag"] = '1'
                break

        #serialize book detail info, all reviews and user review flag dict
        user_review_json = json.dumps(user_review)
        book_info = serializers.serialize('json',list([context['bookobject']])+list(context['book_reviews']))

        data = json.dumps({"review_flag":user_review_json,"book_detail":book_info})


        return JsonResponse(data,encoder=DjangoJSONEncoder, safe=False, **response_kwargs)
```

Comment: Looks like you already send them as json? What did went wrong? Any error?

Comment: @alix I was not able to parse the json string returned this way in jquery ajax call...

Comment: Can you share the returned json here?

Answer (score 1):

it can be simply

```
jsondata = json.dumps(dict)
return HttpResponse(jsondata, content_type='application/json')
```

Comment: I agree with your syntax .. but I was having difficulty in building the dict which is a combination of model instances and a python dict.. someone suggested to use django.core.serializers.python to build the dict and it worked !